# How many jobs have you gotten from your IMDB site?

Tags: imdb, site, credit

Those of you who have IMDB sites, is it worth it?

Have you gotten job opportunities from it?

Care to enlighten?

Comment: Do you mean have your credits listed on IMDB? 
or pay for IMDBPro? 
or pay for an IMDB Resume?


Comment: @tim Sorry - whatever you use to promote yourself via IMDB. How many people have contacted you by merely seeing your credits? Or do you know? I have a few I want to put up there but don't know if it's worth it.. Seems like it's just a bragging rights thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I sincerely doubt anyone finds & hires a sound editor or designer solely by browsing IMDB, that isn't how people make important decisions about who they will potentially collaborate with. But is it important? Definitely! Even if you aren't freelance, who knows what the future holds and you don't want to leave it until you leave your job or whatever to start establishing such things.... When I pitched to do 30 Days of Night I had to send over a proposed crew list to SONY with IMDB links for every member of the team including assistant sound editors, foley editor etc... and that right there is why IMDB is important: credits are officially verified before they appear on IMDB. It's not about bragging, it is about being credited for the work you have done, the same as the credit roller on the end of a film is. And for a director or producer who is considering working with you it is an efficient way of checking out your work history even down to watching trailers & seeing the total budget of projects you have done. (I pay for IMDBPro as it lets me see what producers & directors see ie the total budget on a film, the box office etc as well as contact info for people... and the custom resume allow you to arrange your credit list in the order you prefer, since the main IMDB credit list is chronological.)

Comment: I would always take it with a inch of salt though as my wife has wardrobe credits that we've told them isn't her but are still there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that anybody would contact you from seeing your imdb page alone. It's pretty important for freelancers though; potential clients tend to check you out on there and see what you've done. I'd say it's a good idea to keep it up to date just in case it helps you out one day.

Answer (score 2):

I love the site and am on there almost every day. However my list is like a small snapshot of my work. I have 15 credits listed on there but my real list is 5 times that in reality. It's a great resource but not a complete one. I wonder what the percentage is? How many shows/films are on there compared to how many have been made?

I'm currently job hunting and have made sure there's a link on my applications to my IMDB as in my view there's a certain prestige to being listed there. I've no way to tell but I'm hoping that it'll help me in my quest.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough.....but seriously, folks....

[imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0421174/) has become my resumé. I no longer keep a paper resumé like I used to, but direct potential employers and clients there instead. I think it's easier for all parties; easier for me to update, easier for them to peruse at their leisure, forward to colleagues, etc.

I've had plenty of referrals from imdb (mostly word-of-mouth referrals that were bolstered by my credits on that page) but actual hired jobs? That comes only from a successful face-to-face meeting ending with a handshake.